# Discord Bot command cooldown

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I'm trying to add a cooldown on on my ~hunt command for my Discord Bot. Which only can be used once in 5 minutes. I've tried different ways to program it but it doesn't work for me. Does anyone know a way to add an cooldown on a Discord command. Im currently using c# for it.

Comment: So from what you've said, what have you tried?

Comment: That would be actually pretty easy, but what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would save something like this in a database with the UUID and the timestamp when the last request was processed successfully by this User.

On the next request just check if the User is in the database and the last request is older than 5mins.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a way of storing the GuildId and UserId of the user who called the command as well as the discord bot server time that the method was called. Then whenever that function is called, you check with the data and if the user data matches then see how much time has passed since last time.